# Run python server on VPS

Tags: python, sockets, server, ip, vps

I create a simple python server:

```
import socket
server=socket.socket()
server.bind(("0.0.0.0",8820))
server.listen(1)
(client_socket,client_address)=server.accept()

client_name=client_socket.recv(1024)
client_socket.send("Hello "+client_name)

client_socket.close()
server.close()
```

when I run this script in a VPS I cannot connect to this server
why?
(I get the IP address of the server( with ifconfig command on bash console) and when I run a client script that connect to this address it doesn't connect)

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind the socket server to the vps public IP address and try to avoid ports bellow 10,000 I think most of firewalls prevent incoming connections through ports under 10,000.